# Can we define the infinitesimal deformation map for holomorphic vector bundles via Dolbeault cohomology?

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

I am reading Narasimhan's notes *Deformations of complex structures and holomorphic vector bundles*. In page 198-199 the author introduced the deformation of holomorphic vector bundles on a complex manifold $V$ parametrized
by a complex manifold $T$ to be a holomorphic vector bundle $\mathcal{W}$ on $T \times  V$.

The author then defined the infinitesimal deformation map
$$
\eta_{t_0}: T_{t_0}\to H^1(V,\underline{\text{End}}(\mathcal{W}_{t_0})
$$
for $t_0\in T$.

Notice that the definition in the paper is given in Cech cohomology. On the other hand, in the deformation theory of complex structures of complex manifolds, the analogous Kodaira-Spencer map
$$
\rho_{t_0}: T_{t_0}\to H^1(V,TV)
$$
can be given in both Cech and Dolbeault cohomology, see Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I* Section 9.1.2.

> > So I wonder if we can also define the infinitesimal deformation map $\eta_{t_0}$ in Dolbeault cohomology using connections.

Comment: If you deform a holomorphic vector bundle, the underlying $C^\infty$ vector bundle won't change. If $\bar\partial_0$ is the initial complex structure, then a deformation is given by $\bar\partial_0+ \epsilon A$, where $A$ is a matrix valued $1$-form. Since you want this to be integrable, you have to impose $\bar \partial_0 A=0$. So $A$ defines a cohomology class as above. Probably this what are looking for.